# How can I accurately draw my rotated bitmap?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, matrix, bitmap, bitmapdata

I have a container with masked bitmap in it. The scale and rotation of this container changes at runtime, and I need to draw the masked bitmap but cannot figure out the appropriate matrix calculations to do so.

My code works correctly to reflect position, scale, offset for centering without rotation. When rotated, the angle is correct but the positioning is incorrect - I believe because the dimensions change when the rectangle is rotated.

Can someone help me figure out how to compensate for this in the positioning - here is some code:

```
 // Adjust the transformation matrix to account for the position of the container
        var tMatrix:Matrix = _imgContainer.transform.matrix;

        //Offset for container
        tMatrix.translate(this.x,this.y);

        //Offset for bounds centering
        tMatrix.translate(-_imgContainer.width/2,-_imgContainer.height/2);   

       // Compensate for rotation
       // ????

   var result_bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(_maskedImg.width,_maskedImg.height,true,0x00FFFFFF);
   result_bitmap.lock();
   result_bitmap.draw(_maskedImg,tMatrix,null,null,null,true);
   result_bitmap.unlock();
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide -

b

**EDIT:**
Sorry if I'm not explaining this correctly, let me try again with an image to support. I have a masked bitmap in a container which I'm using as the source to draw a new bitmap. this container can be scaled/rotated at runtime by the user prior to capturing. In order to accomplish this I pass the draw method a transformation matrix based on the container matrix and adjust the tx and ty values to account for the non-zero origin (due to centering). Up to this point it works fine and captures what I would expect.

However - once this container is rotated, the POSITION of the capture is now off again - presumable due to the dimensions changing, therefore the tx/ty offsets now being incorrect for the new dimensions of the container. I simply need to compensate for this, but cannot figure out how.

Does anyone have experience with the transform matrix that can help?? Thanks again for the effort!

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

[image: Hosted by imgur.com]

Comment: Don't think I understand what you're trying to do: can you do a picture or screenshot?

Comment: Updated the question with a better explanation and 2 images for reference - thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI for anyone that might come along with similar problems. I solved my issue by explicitly setting the transformation matrix values and in this **specific order** scale, rotation then translation.

This was instead of copying the transformation matrix from the container. So instead of

```
var tMatrix:Matrix = _imgContainer.transform.matrix;
```

I am setting the values directly in this order:

```
tMatrix.scale (_imgContainer.scaleX, _imgContainer.scaleY);
tMatrix.rotate (_imgContainer.rotation * (Math.PI/180));
tMatrix.translate (_imgContainer.x, _imgContainer.y);
```

Thanks for the effort -

b

Comment: This problem occurs because when you do a translation, the point about which rotations takes place changes according to that translation.
The order of operations you've used here is NOT really a general purpose solution; instead it is specific to the order of transformations the user applied, which your capture code must exactly mirror (albeit with different values).

Comment: Dustman - your assertion that the order of translations is strictly dependent on the order that the user transformed the source bitmap container is incorrect. Regardless of the order in which the scale, position and rotation of the source is applied by the user, the transformation order in the code above consistently renders correctly. -b

Answer (score 0):

If the bitmap is contained inside the container, any transformations applied to the container should also be applied to the things contained within it.

I wouldn't apply any transformations to the bitmap, I'd apply them just to the container.

Comment: All transformations are applied to the container, my question is specifically about the transformation matrix when drawing a bitmap and how to compensate for the rotation during draw.

Comment: Why would rotating bitmap be any different?
Off the top of my head though, I'm thinking the rotation is off a different "center point", so you might want to check the alignment

Comment: The issue is not with rotation of the bitmap - when drawing a new bitmap from source bitmapdata, transformations(scale,rotation, etc) to the source aren't taken into account. You pass in a transformation matrix to transform the source. This transformation matrix with regards to the .tx and .ty values when the source is rotated is what I'm having trouble with. Thanks. -b

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood your question completely, but it's worth nothing that if you rotate a 100x200 object 90 degrees it will give 200x100 for width and height.

There's a number of ways to get around this, but I normally use scaleX/scaleY, as they are not affected by rotations, and multiply those with the original width/height of the clip.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't grasped what you're trying to do 100% either, but I get the basic issue that the rotation you've applied is changing the tx/ty you need to use when applying your transform matrix.

On that basis perhaps this helps: http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/transformmatrix/ Look at the section on "Manipulating Transformation Matrices", particularly the part about ignoring translation values with deltaTransformPoint. It's AS2, but hopefully the principles might get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look. I'm going back and rewriting some of this to see if I can simplify my test case and get closer to a solution. I'll update if I figure it out...